# Appium Python How to launch hybrid app then switch to webview after

Tags: android, python, webview, appium

I have to automate an app. In some section user can browse dropbox, gdrive but has to login before. The login screen is opened in a browser. Here I need to access browser elements which can be done via webview. The issue:

I cant switch from Native context to Webview. With command print driver.contexts only u'Native_APP' is printed. So I tried different things out changed capabilities and with different caps I see Native and Webview.

But how do I run native app and switch later to webview? Am I missing something? Below you can see my caps.

Native and Web context available but cannot launch my app.. :

```
 #set up appium
desired_caps                        = dict()
desired_caps['platformName']        = 'Android'
desired_caps['deviceName']          = 'Android Device'
desired_caps['app']                 = PATH(ARTIFACTS_PATH + 'sample.apk')
desired_caps['appActivity']         = 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.ChromeTabbedActivity'
desired_caps['appPackage']          = 'com.android.chrome'
desired_caps['browser']             = 'Chrome'



driver                              = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

print driver.contexts
```

Can launch my app but without webview context available:

```
#set up appium
    desired_caps                        = dict()
    desired_caps['platformName']        = 'Android'
    desired_caps['deviceName']          = 'Android Device'
    desired_caps['app']                 = PATH(ARTIFACTS_PATH + 'sample.apk')
    desired_caps['appActivity']         = 'com.mysample.sample.HomeActivity'
      desired_caps['appPackage']        = 'com.mysample.sample'


    driver                              = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', 
    print driver.contexts
```

*Had to replace appname and package names due to company rules*

I know the actual command to switch is driver.switch_to.context('Webview')
but I cant switch when there is no webview available in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Webview debugging needs to be set to true by developer in order to perform actions in web view

Answer (score 0):

Provide some sleep or implicit wait so that all contexts loads and see whether you app is printing Webview or not use and if not then ask developers are they using crosswalk or not. If they are using crosswalk(https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597 known issue) then This might help you https://github.com/ITKarel/ChromeDriver

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.